# How would you implement this idiom in ruby?

Tags: ruby

As someone who came from Java background and being a newbie to Ruby,
I was wondering if there is a simple way of doing this with ruby.

```
new_values = foo(bar)
if new_values
  if arr
    arr << new_values
  else 
    arr = new_values
  end
end
```

Comment: So...get an array of values, and if you have already created a variable (as an array) add the values to the array, otherwise set them?

Comment: Can you clarify why it is that you don't know if `arr` exists or not? Is this the first/later passes in a loop? Are you calling a method repeatedly and `arr` should really be `@arr`, an instance variable? Do you want the `new_values` to be added as a single array to the end of `arr`, or concatenated?

Comment: shouldn't the 7th line be arr = [new_values]? or else the 5th arr.concat(new_values)?

Comment: @tokland Exactly my point (and addressed in my answer). I think so, but not sure what @truthSeeker is really trying to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming "arr" is either an array or nil, I would use:

```
arr ||= []
arr << new_values
```

If you're doing this in a loop or some such, there might be more idiomatic ways to do it. For example, if you're iterating a list, passing each value to `foo()`, and constructing an array of results, you could just use:

```
arr = bars.map {|bar| foo(bar) }
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Would arr = bars.map {|bar| foo(bar) } append the result of foo(bar) to the existing arr or create new one on first attempt?

Comment: I'd +1 you if I had votes for the suggestion about a loop; I strongly suspect that this is being done repeatedly and an `inject` solution might even be appropriate.

Comment: @truthSeekr - `.map` collects all the results from the block and stuffs them into a single array, which is returned (and assigned to arr). If you're running that multiple times, there are ways to deal with that, too, but I'll need more context to answer it well. @Phrogz - I considered an inject solution, but it seemed like simple collection, so I went with map. No sense in confusing him too early. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris. I was iterating through an resultset and ended up using .map. It's pretty neat. I would like to learn more about the *var approach suggested by DigitalRoss but yours seemed simpler to grasp.

Answer (score 3):

If I'm understanding you correctly, I would probably do:

```
# Start with an empty array if it hasn't already been set
@arr ||= []

# Add the values to the array as elements
@arr.concat foo(bar)
```

If you use `@arr << values` you are adding the entire array of values to the end of the array as a single nested entry.

Comment: Indeed, Phrogz, I think the OP actually needs a concat. A variation of this in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

#### `arr = [*arr.to_a + [*new_values.to_a]]`

---

Start with:

```
arr ||= []
```

And then, depending on whether `new_values` is an array or not

```
arr += new_values    # if array
arr << new_values    # if not
arr += [*new_values] # if it could be either
```

Furthermore, you can get rid of the test on `new_values` by taking advantage of the fact that `NilClass` implements a `.to_a => []` method and reduce everything to:

```
arry ||= []
arr += [*new_values.to_a]
```

But wait, we can use that trick *again* and make the entire thing into a one-liner:

---

```
arr = [*arr.to_a + [*new_values.to_a]]
```

---

Comment: Not a stupid question at all, *splat* is a mysterious piece of Ruby awesome. *Splat* will add or subtract a level of *"arrayness"* (*collect* or *flatten*) its argument as needed. In this case the *splat* operator is used to *flatten* so that the result is a single array rather than a multilevel one. (In other cases it will *collect* objects and add a level of arrayness such as when used on a formal parameter. Google *ruby splat* for more.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't intend to write an inexcrutable one-liner, but I think this is quite clear. Assuming, as Phrogz, that what you really need is an extend (concat):

```
arr = (arr || []).concat(foo(bar) || [])
```

Or:

```
(arr ||= []).concat(foo(bar) || [])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
new_values = foo(bar)
arr ||= []
arr << new_values if new_values
```